# do I need to use percentages or fixed values in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Bootstrap and Bootstrap 3.. I assume I should always use percentages to specify widths and never fixed values.. is that correct.

I need my row to not go to the whole screen, but only take up as much room as it needs based on the inner elements..I asssume I need to just set the width of the row.. or is there another way?

```
<div class="row" style="width:80%">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>DashBoard Details</legend>

        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <label style="width:100px;display:block">FirstName</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <label style="width:100px;display:block;">Age</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
             <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="submit" />
        </div>


    </fieldset>

</div>
```

Comment: Try sticking with the grid system (e.g. col-...) instead of hard coding widths.  Also, [nesting rows within cols-...](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) is possible. Consider looking into that.

Comment: Jeremy - Thanks for that, but without the width, the fieldset outline goes the whole page... how can I just tell it to only outline what is required (whatever space the internals take?)

Comment: Jeremey - of I see.. nested rows...

Comment: I highly encourage you to read all the bootstrap 3 docs. Well worth your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine this is what you are going for.  The col-... divs must be immediate children of the row div.

> http://jsfiddle.net/742qj/

```
<div style="width:80%">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>DashBoard Details</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label>FirstName</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <label>Age</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <input type="submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Or perhaps

```
<div clas="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>DashBoard Details</legend>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>FirstName</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <label>Age</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <input type="submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but I still need to specify the width in the first row?

Comment: I like the second way, as like you said it gets rid of the width at the top (width="80%")